# Windows: Retrieve recently executed files

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm using C++, but I think it's unrelated in this case. I'd like to retrieve the recently started process's filepath. I'M not sure if such exists at all. I'm not interested in that PID xy has the path "foo", but I'm interested in a history, like the path "foo" was executed. Even better if I'd know when, but not important. Is it possible to retrieve? Is there any specific WinAPI for this?

Comment: i think windows not save history of started processes. but you can write self driver and set PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine[Ex[2]] for get this info in real time

Comment: I might have phrased wrong, I'm not interested in processes, but rather "recently executed files".

Comment: no difference.  "recently executed files" this is exe from which process created ?

Comment: Actually, yes... A process has to be run either way :) The point is that I'm not interested in the process itself or any other information about the process,  but rather the path only. In my case writing a kernel driver is not an option because of the digital signature I'd have to buy.

Comment: you can run L"SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace" via `ExecNotificationQueryAsync`. look for [`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/krnlprov/win32-processstarttrace)

Comment: Another way is through [security auditing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-process-creation).

Comment: A non programming tool: [ProcessMonitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), which can monitor all files used by processes and generate logs. Or simply, use `Windows + R`>`shell:recent` to open the recent item folder.

Comment: Processmonitor is unable to capture "history". shell:recent is quite a great idea, however it seems like it's capturing only a very very limited set of data.

Comment: Windows does not save this history. You can only manually create a process, such as a service, to monitor all the file access and generate history.